# Trouble mapping an existing entity to an embedded form in symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.2

I have an entity which is on the inverse side of a three one-to-one mappings. Entity `FittingStep` is mapped by `FittingStepSingleValue`, etc. `FittingStep` has a field `fittingStepType` which identifies which one of the three entities the `FittingStep` should look for. I want to embed that object in the `FittingStep` edit form.

I have defined forms as services for each of the subforms:

```
services:
    ihear.form.fitting_step_single_value:
        class: Ihear\FittingBundle\Form\FittingStepSingleValueType
        arguments: [@security.context]
        tags:
            -   
                name: form.type
                alias: ihear_fittingbundle_fittingstepsinglevaluetype
    ihear.form.fitting_step_double_value:
        class: Ihear\FittingBundle\Form\FittingStepDoubleValueType
        arguments: [@security.context]
        tags:
            -   
                name: form.type
                alias: ihear_fittingbundle_fittingstepdoublevaluetype
    ihear.form.fitting_step_option:
        class: Ihear\FittingBundle\Form\FittingStepOptionType
        arguments: [@security.context]
        tags:
            -   
                name: form.type
                alias: ihear_fittingbundle_fittingstepoptiontype
```

These service classes look like this (pretty basic)

```
class FittingStepSingleValueType extends AbstractType
{
    private $securityContext;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext)
    {   
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }   

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {   
        $builder
            ->add('max1')
            ->add('description1')
            ->add('fittingStep', 'hidden')
        ;   
    }   

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Ihear\FittingBundle\Entity\FittingStepSingleValue'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ihear_fittingbundle_fittingstepsinglevaluetype';
    }
}
```

My Form uses an EventListener on PRE_SET_DATA to add the appropriate embedded form field:

```
class FittingStepType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {   
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('abbreviation')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('fittingStepType',
                'choice',
                ['choices' => ['SingleValue' => 'SingleValue',
                               'DoubleValue' => 'DoubleValue',
                               'Option' => 'Option'],
                 'empty_value' => 'select one please'])
        ;   

        $formModifier = function(FormInterface $form, $fittingStepType) {
            switch ($fittingStepType) {
                case 'SingleValue':
                    $form->add('fittingStepSingleValue',
                        'ihear_fittingbundle_fittingstepsinglevaluetype');
                    if ($form->has('fittingStepDoubleValue'))
                        $form->remove('fittingStepDoubleValue');
                    if ($form->has('fittingStepOption'))
                        $form->remove('fittingStepOption');
                    break;
                case 'DoubleValue':
                    $form->add('fittingStepDoubleValue',
                        'ihear_fittingbundle_fittingstepdoublevaluetype');
                    if ($form->has('fittingStepSingleValue'))
                        $form->remove('fittingStepSingleValue');
                    if ($form->has('fittingStepOption'))
                        $form->remove('fittingStepOption');
                    break;
                case 'Option':
                    $form->add('fittingStepOption',
                        'ihear_fittingbundle_fittingstepoptiontype');
                    if ($form->has('fittingStepSingleValue'))
                        $form->remove('fittingStepSingleValue');
                    if ($form->has('fittingStepDoubleValue'))
                        $form->remove('fittingStepDoubleValue');
                    break;
            }
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function(FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                // this is the FittingStep
                $data = $event->getData();
                // this is the Entity that contains the value(s)
                // i.e. FittingStepSingleValue
                $fittingStepType = $data->getFittingStepType();
                switch ($fittingStepType) {
                    case 'SingleValue':
                        $formModifier($form, $fittingStepType);
                        break;
                    case 'DoubleValue':
                        $formModifier($form, $fittingStepType);
                        break;
                    case 'Option':
                        $formModifier($form, $fittingStepType);
                        break;
                }
            }
        );
    }
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Ihear\FittingBundle\Entity\FittingStep'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ihear_fittingbundle_fittingsteptype';
    }
}
```

My controller for the edit action:

```
/** 
 * Displays a form to edit an existing FittingStep entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="admin_fittingstep_edit")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function editAction($id)
{   
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('IhearFittingBundle:FittingStep')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'Unable to find FittingStep entity.');
    }   

    $editForm = $this->createForm(new FittingStepType(), $entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );  
}
```

When I try to load the form, I get an exception:

> The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an
>   instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class
>   Ihear\FittingBundle\Entity\FittingStep. You can avoid this error by
>   setting the "data_class" option to
>   "Ihear\FittingBundle\Entity\FittingStep" or by adding a view
>   transformer that transforms an instance of class
>   Ihear\FittingBundle\Entity\FittingStep to scalar, array or an instance
>   of \ArrayAccess.

What am I doing wrong? It seems like there is some disconnect between the object mapping between the entities and the mapping on the form. As a side note, I'm using the `$formModifier` closure successfully in my create form, so it works fine when creating a new entity with the embedded form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The relationship between the entities was referenced by the embedded entity, so I had added a hidden field for the parent entity to the embedded form. This little rascal did not cause any trouble with the creation form, but caused the error above when I embedded the form to edit an existing entity. Thanks @albert for pointing me to that line of code!

```
class FittingStepSingleValueType extends AbstractType
{
    private $securityContext;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext)
    {   
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }   

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {   
        $builder
            ->add('max1')
            ->add('description1')
            // this line was the culprit
            //->add('fittingStep', 'hidden')
        ;   
    }   

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Ihear\FittingBundle\Entity\FittingStepSingleValue'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ihear_fittingbundle_fittingstepsinglevaluetype';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the fittinStep from hidden to Collection

```
->add('fittingStep', 'hidden')
```

Collection doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

```
->add('fittingStep', 'collection', array('type'=>new FittingStepType(), 'label'=>false))
```

Comment: I don't think I want to add a collection field to the form being embedded.